# Magento 2 - Transactional Emails Received with Variable Instead of Content

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

[image]

As you can see by the screenshot, I am getting variables instead of the actual content in transactional emails. This particular template is the New Order Guest template but this happens with New Order as well. I've modified the template but that didn't work. I looked it up but can't find much related to this issue.

The email sends but I get the variables instead of what should be there. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to display customer firstname?

Comment: Yes, I would like the customer's first name but the billing/shipping information, payment method and date after placed on are also wrong/missing.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this :

For customer name :

```
{{var order.getCustomerName()}}
```

For Billing Information :

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}
```

For Shipping Information :

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
```

For payment method :

```
{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}
```

Hope, It will usefull for you !!

Comment: Thanks. This got me on the right track. The templates were loading the wrong variables so I found the right ones using load default.

Comment: Do you have any idea that how to get Guest customer name in credit/shipment email templates?